# Joining machine to domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, active-directory

How can I join my workstation (my personal machine so not in a network) to the domain (Windows Server 2008 R2 is the host).

Thanks

Comment: You probably don't really want to do this. Your existing profile will not be merged with the new local profile of any domain user that logs in.

Comment: Discuss this with your system administrator.

Answer (score 3):

First thing is you talk to an admin and let them know that you want to do this.  They may have a "no personal machines on the network" policy and you risk violating it, which could land you in a heap of bother.

Assuming that you've a version of Windows that *can* join a domain, your domain may be configured to use a user account dedicated to joining machines (this is an MS recommendation).  If so you'll need the user name and password of this account in order to join, which I guess your admin won't idly give you.

Answer (score 0):

What's the operating system?

Non-business versions of Windows explicitly forbid joining a domain. Otherwise, it's just advanced properties of My Computer, and it's on the Computer Name tab.

Comment: Well, that's not *quite* all there is to it. As mh said, you also need a username/password for a domain account that is permitted to join machines

Comment: Yes agreed. I made the assumption the OP was the admin, but on reflection I think that maybe they're not. I would also want to know (as the admin of my network) if someone was just plugging stuff into it, as there are numerous IT policies they should be reminded of (like the one that says don't do that!). IT is so fundamental to so many businesses nowadays, that if your <random plugged in thing> malfunctions and takes even just a part of my network down, the company potentially stands to lose millions. If that happens, I along with several of the senior managers would be gunning for you.